# Thiessen polygon delineation within a feature (polygon) not extent

Tags: shapefile, features, extents, voronoi-thiessen, boundaries

I am trying to create Thiessen (Voronoi) polygons, based on points with a defined shapefile (separated polygons).
The output should be inclusive to the feature. The output I receive now is the rectangular area around the selected points.
Clip my shapefile after the process make some polygons contains area from other points not included.

I need a way or a method to use Thiessen polygons just inside my polygons
(every polygon not affected by other points outside)

Picture 1: My Polygons.

Picture 2: My Result.

NB: As showing in Pic2  the polygon upstream polygons is affected by point from downstream polygon

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

Answer (score 1):

a. Select polygon 1.

b. Select all the points that are inside of selected polygon 1 (tools in ArcGIS and QGIS respect selections so you should only get the point bound by polygon 1.

c. Generate Voronoi diagram, clip the resulting Voronoi diagram using polygon 1.

d. Repeat for polygon 2...

Since you likely have multiple polygons you can use iterators to automate the steps listed above.  [See this link on getting started using iterative tools and models](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html).

Comment: I have a Thousand of polygons in my Shapefile, If I select for every polygons points and create Voronoi Diagram it may take many weeks.
I search a way to generate Voronoi Diagram just inside my polygons

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment.